# How to tell if server has all talk turned on?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How can I tell if the server I am playing on has all talk turned on?

Comment: I think you mean all-talk.

Comment: Be blu; insult red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a simple client-side console command to check whether or not all-talk is enabled.

There are less efficient giveaways, including:

1. You can hear players on the other team speak.
2. You see coloured speech bubbles above your teammates heads when they talk. (It will be a white bubble with a yellow `!` if alltalk is disabled.)
3. Ask in server.
4. The server browser adds an `alltalk` flag to any servers with alltalk enabled. (Although server administrators can remove this tag by force, so it's not 100%)